# What Solid/Liquid will become more dense as it gets colder

Tags: density

I am trying to find a chemical that is similar to spermaceti. A substance that becomes more dense in transition from a liquid to a solid, and conversely the opposite when heated to become a liquid.
I can't buy spermaceti so i need something similar. Help me save the whales!

The boundaries for temp would be a temperature range from 40 degrees C - 0 degrees C
The boundaries for pressure would be 1 atm up to whatever is required.

I realize the most efficient would be gas... hmm I will have to think about that.

Thanks in advance for any ideas :)
ps I have a BS in Medical Lab Science
ヘ( ^o^)ノ＼(^_^ )

Comment: Any wax will do this. It's normal for materials to get denser when they freeze. Water is unusual in doing the opposite

Comment: Stu, if you could give details on the physical properties that you need in your non-spermaceti substance, it would be somewhat easier to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: @JohnRennie - water is somewhat unusual, and likely the main one that most people have encountered. There are at least five elements, and then any number of alloys, that exhibit that behavior, and that isn't even getting into various polymers...

Comment: Well I hope you guys can see this.

Comment: David- The physical properties i would need, I don't understand completely what you are asking, and I don't want to give away to much due to potential future patents. Let us say I am looking for a substance that could be used in a toy submarine that would act like a swim bladder in a fish. Or in the theoretical case of sperm whales, spermaceti. A heating element would make the theoretical artificial spermaceti liquid and cause the "toy submarine" to rise, and the ocean current would cool the spermaceti to cause the "toy submarine" to sink. Sharks are a prob.

Comment: John Rennie, thanks for the info!